# javascript obfuscation as part of build process

Tags: javascript, ant, build, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have seen online javascript obfuscation tools. Would it be feasible or considered reasonable to have such a process run as a part of the build procedure for a web application, or how is obfuscation generally achieved?

Is it more of a manual process of creating a backup of the javascript to store with the project, and then running the contents through an obfuscator before doing a build? It seems like it would be cool to have an ant task that you could include as part of the build to handle that for you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is quite possible and it should be done that way.

I find [JScrambler](https://jscrambler.com) a great solution for code protection and obfuscation, and they have support for build automation with their API clients.
I personally use the [Grunt JScrambler](https://github.com/jscrambler/grunt-jscrambler), but I've also tried the Gulp version.

For your particular case, you might want to take a look at this one [Ant](https://github.com/jscrambler/ant-jscrambler). I didn't tried though. There's a Java client also.

I also test the code after obfuscation, and before deploying it. I basically run my unit tests obfuscated for that.

Comment: As of today, JScrambler does not support the spread operator (...)

Comment: The best obfuscator I’ve come across (granted, I did not try many of them), is obfuscator.io , which can be run on CLI through npm or yarn. It supports ES8. Plus it is free.